# Angular takes a long time to load in browser because of REGEX

Tags: angular

It takes almost 30 seconds to refresh my app (in dev mode). I checked in the performance tab of the chrome debugger, and found out that a specific regex takes 17 seconds to run:

```
var _ruleRe = /(\s*)([^;\{\}]+?)(\s*)((?:{%BLOCK%}?\s*;?)|(?:\s*;))/g;
```

It is used in the method processRules in vendors.js file. I tried to search for it, but I didn't find any specific information.

```
Angular CLI: 7.0.6 
Node: 8.12.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular:
...

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.10.6
@angular-devkit/core         7.0.6
@angular-devkit/schematics   7.0.6
@schematics/angular          7.0.6
@schematics/update           0.10.6
rxjs                         6.3.3
typescript                   3.1.6
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Strange Behaviour, curious to know the reason!

Comment: Vendor.bundle.js is all your third party libraries bunded.  What NPM packages have you added?

Comment: Take a look at this. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20105

Answer (score 0):

OK, so the problem was that an HTML file was defined in the styleUrls. It was not easy to find :-)